# how to open a .dsr crystal report in vb6 needs startup form

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a DSR file containing a crystal report, but everytime I try to run the project, the error `Must have start up form` pops up. As far as I can tell, I have a `crptEmployeep9infoView` ICR designer in the project explorer window only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VB IDE is telling you it doesn't know how to start the application.

- Go to the Project properties page.
- Ensure the General tab is selected.
- On the top right, there is a drop down box labeled "Startup Object"
- You should have either a start up form selected, or "Sub Main" selected.

If neither of these options exist, create a form, or open a BAS file and create a Sub Main. This object should then run your report.